# dont see material propeties when i have render engine selected to Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine, properties

Hi everyone I have a question, I just started using blender and I'm watching a video of making a donut to learn the basics, on the video they recommend changing the render engine type to cycles and I do that and it makes the 3d donut look better, after changing the engine he goes to material properties and keeps making changes like the color or the roughness, but when I go there I don't get those options the only way for me to change the material properties is to change the render engine back to eevee do any change necessary then switch it back to cycles

The first picture shows the material properties I get for Eevee render engine

[image: eevee material properties]

The 2nd image is the material properties options that I get when I have the render engine to Cycles

[image: cycles material properties]

Is this normal or how do I fix this problem I'm having

Comment: That is strange - they should be there. I'm guessing you're using 2.91? Are you using an alpha build? It shouldn't matter because I tested on 2.91 alpha and I cannot recreate your problem, but I assume the alpha version is more prone to variable behavior on different systems. Maybe try a different version? (anything 2.83+ is solid)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply
I downloaded a older version (2.83) and open the same project and had the same issue.
Since that didn't work I tried something different and  open the last version (2.91), but created a new general project and change the rendering to cycles, then I went to the material properties of the square that shows up when you first create a new project and I did see the options there, so I ended up using the append option to import the objects from the old project to the new one and I was able to see the material properties of those object too

Comment: Damn, that was going to be my other suggestion - copy and paste into a new file.  Sometimes (not often) things get either messed up with the file, or the project settings, and getting your scene into a new file helps for some unexplained reason. Anyway, glad you got a working solution.